# Can a system task like $display be used in code in Quartus II?

Tags: verilog, simulation, quartus-ii

I started learning verilog recently and I tried this simple code:

```
module hello_world ;

initial begin
$display ("Hello World by jai");
#10 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Then, I set this module as Top_Level Entity, and clicked Analysis and Synthesis. Then comes the error:

> Error: Can't synthesize current design -- Top partition does not contain any logic.

How can I use these tasks in Quartus, or can they be only used in software where we can write testbench (like Xilinx ise)?

I'm using Quartus II 9.1sp2.

Comment: Do you know that this code can not be synthesized, so so what ate you trying to do with this?

Comment: While these statements are not synthesizable, major FPGA vendors do offer a scheme which you can compile in to monitor values of the running design via the programmer cable, as a sort of built-in logic analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a *verilog simulator*, rather than synthesis tool to execute code like this.